# Smoke is Noisy with background image

Tags: compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I am trying to composite a smoke simulation to a background image, but some of the smoke is noisy in thinner areas. How do I fix the issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: increasing the sample count seems to help but not completely. even with a sample count of 300 (the images are 12). I would like to find a solution that doesn't require crazy render time.

Comment: Well, that's usually what you can use denoising for... And 300 (without denoising) is not that much, some people render with 1000 to 5000 samples.